# Exception when starting zxing CaptureActivity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-support-library, zxing

I have an android project in which I added Zxing/Android jar as a External Jar. In my application I am trying to start CaptureActivity from my own activity via intent with this code:

```
// start Google bar-code scanner
Intent intent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), CaptureActivity.class);
intent.setAction(Intents.Scan.ACTION);

// this stops saving your bar-code in bar-code scanner app's history
intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.SAVE_HISTORY, false);
// this puts text message on the scanning screen
intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.PROMPT_MESSAGE, message);
// scan only product bar-codes
intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.MODE, Intents.Scan.PRODUCT_MODE);

activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

, and when I do this I get this exception:

> 11-21 13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.myappname/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error
>   inflating class alpha 11-21 13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
>   11-21 13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
>   11-21 13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:142) 11-21
>   13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
>   11-21 13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 11-21
>   13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 11-21 13:08:33.163:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(6414):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118) 11-21
>   13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 11-21
>   13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 11-21 13:08:33.163:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(6414):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>   11-21 13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605) 11-21
>   13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 11-21 13:08:33.163:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(6414): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
>   Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class alpha 11-21
>   13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):     at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:441)
>   11-21 13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):   at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:317)
>   11-21 13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):   at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
>   11-21 13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):   at
>   android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:272)
>   11-21 13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):   at
>   android.preference.PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(PreferenceManager.java:485)
>   11-21 13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):   at
>   android.preference.PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(PreferenceManager.java:444)
>   11-21 13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):   at
>   com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.onCreate(CaptureActivity.java:144)
>   11-21 13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275) 11-21
>   13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   11-21 13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
>   11-21 13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):   ... 11 more 11-21
>   13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.preference.alpha" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.myappname-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.myappname-1,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]] 11-21 13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):
>     at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>   11-21 13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497) 11-21
>   13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457) 11-21
>   13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):     at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:375)
>   11-21 13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):   at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:417)
>   11-21 13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):   at
>   android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:428)
>   11-21 13:08:33.163: E/AndroidRuntime(6414):   ... 20 more

This worked for me before and now I updated my android-support-v7-appcompat library, and now I have this error. I added android-support-v7-appcompat library as an android library in my project. Can't figure out what is causing this.

Comment: Which xml file are you referring?

Comment: are you calling the intent from fragment?

Comment: No . I am calling it from my activity via some helper class (the actual call (code stated above) is in the helper class).

Comment: try replace activity.getApplicationContext() with context of your helper class...

Comment: What do you mean "with context of your helper class"? My helper class is just a plain java class, it does not extend Context.
I tried:
`Intent intent = new Intent(activity, CaptureActivity.class);`
, where activity is my calling activity, but I get same exception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95794/discussion-between-rishad-appat-and-jovankricka).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding **Zxing**:

- **android** project (as an existing Android project),
- **android-core** project (as an existing Maven project) and
- **core** project (as an existing Maven project)

, in my workspace, and referencing **Zxing** **android** project as Android library in my application.
Previously I was just adding **Zxing** **android** and **core** jars as External Jars in my applications Build Path.